# Can Android's Linux kernel be run/emulated through command line in the terminal?

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I'm working in a project where we're customizing Android's Linux kernel. In this project we're trying to find a way to run the just compiled kernel within the terminal, through some sort of command line. I've searched for things over the web but haven't found anything...

Is it possible to run the kernel binary of the AOSP Linux kernel within a terminal? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: How does one run a kernel binary from a shell in general? AFAIK, a Linux kernel isn't a userland application that you can just run from the shell on any Linux environment (e.g., Ubuntu), let alone Android.

Comment: Hi Commons, thanks for the reply. I think I haven't put it well... I'm not trying to run the kernel like an application, as it is really not possible. I'm trying to run it by using some sort of emulation, inside a VM or something like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a version of the Android AOSP kernel for the emulator and run it there.  Look for the "goldfish" kernel then explore the 'emulator' command and qemu options to pass it a custom kernel to load.